# Artifacts between pipeline tasks in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I use the Gitlab CE edition and I setup my classic build pipeline (build, test, deploy). The build step creates an application of around 1GB (500 MB as zipped artifact). The artifact is uploaded to the server and the next gitlab runner downloads it again to test it. Is there a way to set an “affinity” for a gitlab runner, so exactly the machine which just built the binary can continue using the binaries to test it?

One option would be to merge the build and test step into a single one, but I am looking for alternatives. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had exactly the same issue using `cmake`, and had to combine the build and test step into one to save time from zipping and unzipping large build directories.

There is an open issue on using [sticky runners](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/17497), where one pipeline will always use the same runner and save the workspace between jobs, however that is a while away from being completed it seems.